# Java Stream convert List into Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class `PlayerAndCountry` :

```
class PlayerAndCountry {
    private Country country;
    private Player player;
}
```

And a `List<PlayerAndCountry>`

I would like my final Map like this : `Map<Country,List<Player>>`

I know how to get `Map<Country, List<PlayerAndCountry>>` but not `Map<Country,List<Player>>`

Comment: `list.stream().collect(groupingBy(PlayerAndCountry::getCountry,             mapping(PlayerAndCountry::getPlayer, toList())));` Here, `Collectors` is static import: `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Collectors.mapping` to achieve it:

```
Map<Country, List<Player>> collect = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PlayerAndCountry::getCountry,
                Collectors.mapping(PlayerAndCountry::getPlayer, Collectors.toList()))
        );
```